# How to search for a message in Apple Messages app and read messages before and after

Tags: messages, search

I frequently need to search for messages on the apple Messages app (on my mac). After I find the right message, I sometimes want to look at the messages that were sent before and after.

It's easy enough to read the messages before (I just scroll up). However, it does not let me scroll down to see the messages after. What can I do?